# Excel cell showing as negative regardless of positive entry "but" still calculting correctly using autosum

Tags: excel, formatting

This is a hard one to explain but I have a spreadsheet i'm working on and a particular column needs to always display as negative amount -$
To avoid missing the negative I want to format the cells to just enter a positive and then show as negative "but" still autosum correctly.

Example -$25.50 + -$75.00 autosum equals -$100.50

Problem I have is when trying to format I can never get to autosum to -$100.50 but end up with -$49.50 and decreasing back towards $0.00

What I really want is something that will look like this with a cell format in place.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Not at all sure what you are asking (and suspect this is *not* a wise move!) but with this (Custom) format:

```
-$00.00
```

an entry of 25.5 with show as  `-$25.50`, one of 75 will show as `-$75.00` and AutoSum the two as `-$100.50`.